# Flexboxlayout Spacing between items programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I've this Flexboxlayout definition ([official Google library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)):

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:dividerDrawableHorizontal="@drawable/flexboxlayout_divider"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:justifyContent="space_between"
    app:showDividerHorizontal="middle">
```

Now I want to create the same programmatically:

```
FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(activity);
flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_BETWEEN);
flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

What I'm missing is the `app:dividerDrawableHorizontal` and `app:showDividerHorizontal` attributes and didn't find any method to set them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it extends from `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` and `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

you can just do

```java
FlexboxItemDecoration itemDecoration = new FlexboxItemDecoration(context);
itemDecoration.setOrientation(FlexboxItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL); // or VERTICAL or BOTH
itemDecoration.setDrawable(drawable); // replace with actual drawable
myRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```